How to read JWT token data with correct typing C#
I have a problem when reading the data saved in JWT, it is returning everything as a string, the correct thing would be to ensure that the returned values ​​are in the correct typing, for example the firstAccess field saves a boolean true or false but is returning a string "true" or "false", I believe that this is not a good practice. How can I ensure that it returns the correct typing?
JWT:
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_access": false,
  "nbf": 1722250357,
  "exp": 1722279157,
  "iat": 1722250357
}


C#:
 string token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", 
 "");
 var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
 var firstAccess = jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "first_access")?.Value;

  if (firstAccess == "false")
      return BadRequest(new { message = ErrorMessages.ChangePasswordDenied });


the returned values from your JWT token have the correct types, you need to convert them after extracting them from the token. Since JWT claims are typically strings, you must explicitly convert them to their expected types.

Claims are saved as Type/Value with the string type, Check
So there is no built-in way to get value as a boolean but you can map token payload to a custom model:
public class TokenPayloadModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("first_access")]
    public bool FirstAccess { get; set; }

    //other props if needed
}

JwtSecurityToken has a property called RawPayload which we can use it to deserialize payload to our model:
var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;

var payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TokenPayloadModel>(jwtToken.RawPayload);

if(payload?.FirstAccess)
{/*.....*/}


